# How can I make a modal window (colorbox) load javascript (and not just the html)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have POST button which loads a colorbox modal window, using this code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox2.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cboxFormButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.colorbox({
      href: $form.attr('action'),
      transition:"elastic",
      opacity:0.5,
      data: {
                a: $form.find('input[name="a"]').val(),
                b: $form.find('input[name="b"]').val()
                }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form action="rrr2.php" method="POST" target="_blank" class="">
    <input  name="a" type="hidden" value="2"/>
     <input  name="b" type="hidden" value="2"/>
    <input type="submit" class="button cboxFormButton" value="Test">
</form>
```

I would need to insert a javascript tracking snippet into rrr2.php, so anytime that button was clicked, it would be tracked. So I've decided to test whether javascript in general would function if loaded from that window, and simply put just for testing, another colorbox code in the rrr2.php file (same code as above more or less), but it doesn't work.
seems like only the html is processed.

Why does it happen, and how can I overcome this?

**EDIT:** is this suppose to make it work?

```
<script>


    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".cboxFormButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.colorbox({
      href: $form.attr('action'),
      transition:"elastic",
      opacity:0.5,
      data: {
                a: $form.find('input[name="a"]').val(),
                b: $form.find('input[name="b"]').val()
                }
        });

    $.get('rrr2.php');

        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a separate AJAX call to the click event.

```
$(".cboxFormButton").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var $form = $(this).closest('form');

    $.colorbox({
      href: $form.attr('action'),
      transition:"elastic",
      opacity:0.5,
      data: {
        a: $form.find('input[name="a"]').val(),
        b: $form.find('input[name="b"]').val()
      }
    });

    // run simple get request to track click
    $.get('rrr2.php');
});
```

Comment: Should it be like it looks now in my edited post? it didn't change anything, still no reaction

Comment: I meant add that to the current click event you have. Please see my edit.

Comment: I'm afraid it still doesn't work, I've edited the code again in my post according to your suggestion, still nothing happens when I click it...

Comment: Does rrr2.php need any values from say the querystring? Or you just simply hit the page.

Comment: basically it does, but even when I remove all the php properties from that page, the result is the same, no response.